# processing a list in java

Tags: java, arrays, list, file

From an arrayliste  I want to extract N array 
the stracture of the arraylist is :

- number of new array
- size of the first array
- element of the fist
- array size of the second array
- element of the second array
- ...

Any one can help me please. How Can I extract these number in new  N array?

exp

```
50       new array's number
3         ( size of tab1= 3)
2157      first element of the first array ==> tab1[1]= 2157
158       second element of the first array==> tab1[2]= 2158
2172      third element of the first array==> tab1[3]=2172
12        The second array has 12 samples (size of tab2=12)
2360     first element of the second array ==>  tab2[1]= 2360
2367     second element of the second array ==>  tab2[2]= 2367
2375
2375
```

Comment: What you have tried already?

Comment: you should show some efforts of your own. SO is not a free code service, people help each other here, not do each other's work

Comment: I posted my suggestion (code) ,please check and give me your opinion

Answer (score 0):

First, I have not understood much of what you are trying to do. Secondly and more seriously, I’m much in doubt whether I am doing you a favour or the opposite by writing this much code for you. You’d probably learn more by writing it yourself. Anyway, you can take it or ignore it.

I like to separate the generation of lists from the extraction of information from lists, so would like to call two different methods:

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listOfArrayLists = generateLists();
    extractInfo(listOfArrayLists);
```

(my usual style is to write the method call first and the method afterwards, you may prefer it the other way around). Here are the methods:

```
private static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> generateLists() {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<Integer> newArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    newArrayList.add(2157);
    newArrayList.add(158);
    newArrayList.add(2172);
    result.add(newArrayList);

    newArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    newArrayList.add(2360);
    newArrayList.add(2357);
    newArrayList.add(2375);
    result.add(newArrayList);

    newArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    newArrayList.add(725);
    result.add(newArrayList);

    return result;
}

private static void extractInfo(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listOfArrayLists) {
    System.out.println("Number of array lists: " + listOfArrayLists.size());
    for (ArrayList<Integer> al : listOfArrayLists) {
        System.out.println("Size of list: " + al.size());
        System.out.println("Elements:");
        for (Integer i : al) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

The code prints:

```
Number of array lists: 3
Size of list: 3
Elements:
2157
158
2172
Size of list: 3
Elements:
2360
2357
2375
Size of list: 1
Elements:
725
```

I hope you understand the code and that you’ll be able to learn from it. I hope — if this is your ambition — one day you’ll be so good that you can return the favour and write some code for me. :-)